# How to generate random numbers in a data.frame with range

Tags: r, random, dataframe, seq

I have a `data.frame` which I want to generate random numbers each list by a sequence.

I used `sample` function to create random numbers but even I created random numbers for list `[[1]]`, for set  `[[2]]` same numbers produced again. So, here how can I create different random numbers for the set `[[2]]`.

here is the simple code;

```
data.list <- lapply(1:2, function(x) {
nrep <- 1
time <- rep(seq(90,54000,by=90),times=nrep) 
Mx <- rep(sort(sample(seq(0.012,-0.014,length.out = 600),replace=TRUE)), times=nrep)
My <- rep(sort(sample(seq(0.02,-0.02,length.out = 600),replace=TRUE)), times=nrep)
Mz <- rep(sort(sample(seq(-1,1,length.out=600),replace=TRUE)), times=nrep)
data.frame(time,Mx,My,Mz,set_nbr=x)
})
```

this is provide the 5 first lines of each of datasets

```
[[1]]
      time       Mx            My           Mz       set_nbr
1      90 -1.391319e-02 -2.000000e-02 -1.000000000       1
2     180 -1.386978e-02 -1.986644e-02 -1.000000000       1
3     270 -1.386978e-02 -1.973289e-02 -0.996661102       1
4     360 -1.382638e-02 -1.973289e-02 -0.993322204       1
5     450 -1.382638e-02 -1.973289e-02 -0.979966611       1  
..     ..  ....            ....         ....           ...

[[2]]

      time       Mx            My           Mz       set_nbr
1      90 -1.395659e-02 -0.0200000000 -1.000000000       2
2     180 -1.391319e-02 -0.0199332220 -0.993322204       2
3     270 -1.386978e-02 -0.0199332220 -0.993322204       2
4     360 -1.386978e-02 -0.0199332220 -0.993322204       2
5     450 -1.382638e-02 -0.0199332220 -0.986644407       2
..     ..  ....            ....         ....           ...
```

EDIT 1:

regarding to @bgoldst answer now I can produce different numbers

```
set.seed(1);
data.list <- lapply(1:2, function(x) {
nrep <- 1;
time <- rep(seq(90,54000,by=90),times=nrep);
Mx <- rep(sort(runif(600,-0.014,0.012)),times=nrep);
My <- rep(sort(runif(600,-0.02,0.02)),times=nrep);
Mz <- rep(sort(runif(600,-1,1)),times=nrep);
data.frame(time,Mx,My,Mz,set_nbr=x);
});
```

On the other hand when I change `nrep <- 3;` same numbers are created for each `nrep`. This is the thing I want to avoid from the beginning.

EDIT 2:

@bgoldst showed that `replicate` does the job!

Comment: Don't you need to specify how many numbers you want `sample` to pick ? I think you're just keeping the whole `seq` vector here.

Comment: @Vincent Maybe that can also work. But I dont know how to set:(

Comment: I've looked closer at your code and numbers produced in each dataset are different... Can you provide the 5 first lines of each of your datasets ?

Comment: you can see that some numbers are reproduced again. This is not I want. I would like to have completely different numbers for `Mx`,`My` and `Mz` (very small difference is Ok).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may have some confusion about how [`sample()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sample.html) works.

First, let's examine `sample()`'s behavior with respect to this simple vector:

```
1:5;
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

When you pass a multi-element vector to `sample()` it basically just randomizes the order. This means you'll get a different result every time, or rather, to state it more precisely, the longer the vector is, the less likely you are to get the same result twice:

```
set.seed(1); sample(1:5); sample(1:5); sample(1:5);
## [1] 2 5 4 3 1
## [1] 5 4 2 3 1
## [1] 2 1 3 4 5
```

This means if you sort it immediately after sampling, then you'll get the same result every time. And if the original vector was itself sorted, then the result will also be equal to that original vector. This will be true regardless how `sample()` randomized the order, because the order is always restored by [`sort()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sort.html):

```
set.seed(1); sort(sample(1:5)); sort(sample(1:5)); sort(sample(1:5));
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Now if you add `replace=T` (or just `rep=T` if you like to take advantage of partial matching for concision, which I do), then you're *not* just randomizing the order, you're selecting `size` elements with replacement, where `size` is the vector length if you didn't provide `size` explicitly. This means you can get repeated elements in the result:

```
set.seed(1); sample(1:5,rep=T); sample(1:5,rep=T); sample(1:5,rep=T);
## [1] 2 2 3 5 2
## [1] 5 5 4 4 1
## [1] 2 1 4 2 4
```

And so, if you sort the result, you (likely) *won't* get back the original vector, because some elements will have been repeated, and some elements will have been omitted:

```
set.seed(1); sort(sample(1:5,rep=T)); sort(sample(1:5,rep=T)); sort(sample(1:5,rep=T));
## [1] 2 2 2 3 5
## [1] 1 4 4 5 5
## [1] 1 2 2 4 4
```

That's exactly what is happening with your code. Your output vectors *are* different between the two list components, because you're sampling with replacement before sorting, which means different repetitions and omissions of the elements will occur for each list component. But since you're sampling from the same sequence and you're sorting the result, you're bound to get similar-looking results for each list component, even though they're not identical.

I think what you might be looking for is random deviates from a uniform distribution. You can get these from [`runif()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Uniform.html):

```
set.seed(1); runif(5,-0.014,0.012);
## [1] -0.0070967748 -0.0043247786  0.0008941874  0.0096134025 -0.0087562698
set.seed(1); runif(5,-0.02,0.02);
## [1] -0.009379653 -0.005115044  0.002914135  0.016328312 -0.011932723
set.seed(1); runif(5,-1,1);
## [1] -0.4689827 -0.2557522  0.1457067  0.8164156 -0.5966361
```

Thus, your code would become:

```
set.seed(1);
data.list <- lapply(1:2, function(x) {
    nrep <- 1;
    time <- rep(seq(90,54000,by=90),times=nrep);
    Mx <- rep(sort(runif(600,-0.014,0.012)),times=nrep);
    My <- rep(sort(runif(600,-0.02,0.02)),times=nrep);
    Mz <- rep(sort(runif(600,-1,1)),times=nrep);
    data.frame(time,Mx,My,Mz,set_nbr=x);
});
```

Which gives:

```
lapply(data.list,head);
## [[1]]
##   time          Mx          My         Mz set_nbr
## 1   90 -0.01395224 -0.01994741 -0.9967155       1
## 2  180 -0.01394975 -0.01991923 -0.9933909       1
## 3  270 -0.01378866 -0.01980934 -0.9905714       1
## 4  360 -0.01371306 -0.01977090 -0.9854065       1
## 5  450 -0.01371011 -0.01961713 -0.9850108       1
## 6  540 -0.01365998 -0.01960718 -0.9846628       1
##
## [[2]]
##   time          Mx          My         Mz set_nbr
## 1   90 -0.01398426 -0.01997718 -0.9970438       2
## 2  180 -0.01398293 -0.01989651 -0.9931286       2
## 3  270 -0.01397330 -0.01988715 -0.9923425       2
## 4  360 -0.01396455 -0.01957807 -0.9913645       2
## 5  450 -0.01384501 -0.01939597 -0.9892001       2
## 6  540 -0.01382531 -0.01931913 -0.9889356       2
```

---

**Edit:** It looked from your question like you wanted the random numbers to be different *between list components*, that is to say, between the components generated from the 1:2 passed as the first argument to `lapply()`. The repetition of each random vector `nrep` times *within* each list component didn't appear to be relevant, partly because you set `nrep` to 1, so there wasn't any actual repetition.

But that's ok, we can achieve this requirement by using `replicate()` instead of `rep()`, because `replicate()` actual runs its expression argument once for every repetition. We also have to flatten the result, because `replicate()` by default returns a matrix, and we want a straight vector:

```
set.seed(1);
data.list <- lapply(1:2, function(x) {
    nrep <- 2;
    time <- rep(seq(90,54000,by=90),times=nrep);
    Mx <- c(replicate(nrep,sort(runif(600,-0.014,0.012))));
    My <- c(replicate(nrep,sort(runif(600,-0.02,0.02))));
    Mz <- c(replicate(nrep,sort(runif(600,-1,1))));
    data.frame(time,Mx,My,Mz,set_nbr=x);
});
lapply(data.list,function(x) x[c(1:6,601:606),]);
## [[1]]
##     time          Mx          My         Mz set_nbr
## 1     90 -0.01395224 -0.01993431 -0.9988590       1
## 2    180 -0.01394975 -0.01986782 -0.9948254       1
## 3    270 -0.01378866 -0.01981143 -0.9943576       1
## 4    360 -0.01371306 -0.01970813 -0.9789037       1
## 5    450 -0.01371011 -0.01970022 -0.9697986       1
## 6    540 -0.01365998 -0.01969326 -0.9659567       1
## 601   90 -0.01396582 -0.01997579 -0.9970438       1
## 602  180 -0.01394750 -0.01997375 -0.9931286       1
## 603  270 -0.01387607 -0.01995893 -0.9923425       1
## 604  360 -0.01385108 -0.01994546 -0.9913645       1
## 605  450 -0.01375113 -0.01976155 -0.9892001       1
## 606  540 -0.01374467 -0.01973125 -0.9889356       1
##
## [[2]]
##     time          Mx          My         Mz set_nbr
## 1     90 -0.01396979 -0.01999198 -0.9960861       2
## 2    180 -0.01390373 -0.01995219 -0.9945237       2
## 3    270 -0.01390252 -0.01991559 -0.9925640       2
## 4    360 -0.01388905 -0.01978123 -0.9890171       2
## 5    450 -0.01386718 -0.01967644 -0.9835435       2
## 6    540 -0.01384351 -0.01958008 -0.9822988       2
## 601   90 -0.01396739 -0.01989328 -0.9971255       2
## 602  180 -0.01396433 -0.01985785 -0.9954987       2
## 603  270 -0.01390700 -0.01984074 -0.9903196       2
## 604  360 -0.01376890 -0.01982715 -0.9902251       2
## 605  450 -0.01366110 -0.01979802 -0.9829480       2
## 606  540 -0.01364868 -0.01977278 -0.9812671       2
```

Comment: thank you very much for very clear explonation. The information you provide to me is very instructive. I will use `runif`

Comment: I come to realize that if I change `nrep` to 2 or 3,4,5 you will see that all values repeated again and again, My point about this question was how to change this number in each repetetation?

Comment: thanks man, I have a question about how  to become expertise like you in R, I mean when you see the problem how do you become understand and solve it very quickly? should I go with R books or web videos? I am trying to learn one small piece everyday but it seems not enough:(

Comment: @aoronbarlow R is one of the most difficult languages I've ever learnt. For me, probably only C++ is more difficult, and then only the more advanced template stuff in C++. I'd say it's all about experience, experience, experience, and being diligent in recognizing patterns in the language, like `rep()` vs. `replicate()`, and `ave()` vs. `aggregate()` vs. `by()`, and the 8 functions in the apply family (actually there are a couple of others as well...), and stuff like that. The more experience you have, the more quickly and effectively you'll be able to solve problems.

Comment: Yes, go through as many books and web videos and online tutorials as you can, until you start to feel like you know all the information you're seeing. That's the best way to get experience with the language.

Comment: I feel that R is the best tool for me because I have lots of simulation outputs. to analyze those output first I need to process data and use some `function`. Finding proper code is sometime very bothersome but once I do it I save lots of time:) thanks for comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79728/discussion-between-aoron-barlow-and-bgoldst).